# WPF ClickOnce not downloading properly (404)

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I've been looking around on SO and on Google, but come back empty-handed.

This is my issue:
I've recently set up a Clickonce application in VS2013. 
(C# WPF, blank solution).

When I initially attempted to deploy the application it would download well, but not install without issues. I then started excluding files in the prerequisites, which has resulted in this stacktrace:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.10586.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1078.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1080.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.10586.0 (th2_release.151029-1700)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://jabero05/WPFTest/Co_test.application
                        Server      : Microsoft-IIS/10.0
                        X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET
    Deployment Provider url     : http://jabero05/Co_test/Co_test.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://jabero05/WPFTest/Co_test.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading http://jabero05/Co_test/Co_test.application did not succeed.
        + The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [03/06/2016 09:58:56] : Activation of http://jabero05/WPFTest/Co_test.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [03/06/2016 09:58:56] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://jabero05/Co_test/Co_test.application did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirect(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.FollowDeploymentProviderUri(SubscriptionStore subStore, AssemblyManifest& deployment, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

I've since receiving that error attempted to retrace myself by re-adding the prerequisites, but to no avail - I keep getting above mentioned error.

As you can see it is throwing a 404 error whilst being on my localhost (using IIS).

Could anyone tell me what I might be missing?

EDIT:

[image: Solution]

[image: IIS]

Comment: check is your path `http://jabero05/Co_test/Co_test.application` correct ?

Comment: Looks like an incorrect `ProviderURL` (labeled 'Install URL' in Visual Studio UI).

Comment: See edit for the URLs. The solution is published fine, but the deployment seems to be the issue.

Comment: It is not the deployment.  first make sure with an IE browser that the URL is reachable.  Then start using fiddler to help isolate issue.  Compare the http headers in working location with http headers in non working location.  The problem may be a different version of IE is installed on working and non working locations.  The website could be blocked in the non working application that is why I suggested using an IE.  A Certificate may be missing on non working location.  You can try removing in IE history cookies that sometimes solves these issues.

Comment: Found the issue. I had set the update-URL to be different from the publish-URL.